# Descontruct array of objects to get nested values ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like:

```
const array = [
{
  name: 'object1', 
  value: true, 
  parameters: [
   { name: 'inner1', value: true},
   { name: 'inner2', value: false},
 ]
},
{
  name: 'object2', 
  value: false,
}

];
```

I need to get value of each object in array.
To get object1 and object2 values I have used

`const [{value: object1}, {value: object2}] = array;`

How can I get `values` of objects which are in `parameters` array? How to deconstruct it in right way? Cannot find the right way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use `parameters:` and keep destructuring:

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'object1',
    value: true,
    parameters: [{
        name: 'inner1',
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 'inner2',
        value: false
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'object2',
    value: false,
  }
];

const [{ parameters: [
  { value: value1 },
  { value: value2 }
]}] = array;
console.log(value1, value2);
```

But that's not remotely readable IMO. I'd prefer to use standard dot/bracket notation to get to the `parameters` array, and `.map` to extract the values:

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'object1',
    value: true,
    parameters: [{
        name: 'inner1',
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 'inner2',
        value: false
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'object2',
    value: false,
  }
];

const values = array[0].parameters.map(({ value }) => value);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: But then you've still got to perform destructuring on `values` as it's an Array?

Comment: @Dan If OP *really wants* standalone variables, sure, but that's pretty weird IMO. Could also do `const [value1, value2] = array[0].parameters.map(...`

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and map the values of `paramters` only.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'object1', value: true, parameters: [{ name: 'inner1', value: true }, { name: 'inner2', value: false }] }, { name: 'object2', value: false }],
    values = array.flatMap(({ parameters = []}) => parameters.map(({ value }) => value));

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

The deconstruction must follow the shape of the object it is deconstructing. A good way to think of it in situations like this, is to just copy the object itself, and then replace each value with a variable name to assign that value to

```
// Object from which to deconstruct values
const myArray = [{
    name: 'object1', 
    value: true, 
    parameters: [
       { name: 'inner1', value: true},
       { name: 'inner2', value: false}]
    }];

// Deconstruction
const [{
    name: nameVar, 
    value: valueVar, 
    parameters: [
        { name: paramNameVar1, value: valueVar1},
        { name: paramNameVar2, value: valueVar2}]

     }] = myArray
```

Of course once you start getting more complex objects, it is possably more effort, less readable, and less efficient to deconstruct this way.

Comment: The question is about how to deconstruct an object/hash with nested values.

The deconstruction must follow the shape of the object it is deconstructing.
OP was already getting top level values, but was unable to get at the values that were sitting inside a nested array.

A good way to think about deconstructing like this is to basically copy the object itself, and then replace the values with the var names you would like to assign those values to.

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime!